# How to validate a java.sql.timestamp in JSF if format is different form the java.sql.timestamp in view

Tags: java, jsf

In my application there is an **inputfield** where the user should enter a **timestamp** like **(yyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS**). In the database (DB2) the field is a timestamp **(yyy-mm-dd hh.mm:ss:SSSSSS)**. Till now I coded a jsf converter which converts in the **getAsObject** method the string with the format above into a java.sql.timestamp and the **getAsString** method back again. The **inputfield** maps to a timestamp of the backing bean. Everything works fine but unfortunately I can't write a standard validator which I can use directly on field of the backing bean (annotation) as the format in the inputfield is not conform to the java.sql.timestamp. If the validation happens on the view I guess there will be the same problem as the value maps also to the timestamp field.

What is the standard procedure to validate a timestamp format in the view **(yyy-mm-dd-hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS)** if the field of the backing bean has the java.sql.timestamp ?

Comment: `java.sql.*` is part of JDBC - those classes are sub classes of `java.util.Date`. Thus, you should not be using `java.sql.timestamp` in managed beans (on web parts). Instead, make use of it in the business logic (database side) - the service layer - JPA, plain JDBC or something else whatever you are interested in. On the web layer (managed beans/models), you should be using poorly designed `java.util.Date` (or its friends like Joda Time, Java Time in Java 8 or otherwise). In a nutshell, use `java.util.Date*` (or its friends) on the Java side (JSF) and `java.sql.*` on database (JDBC) side.

Comment: Models (managed beans/JSF) should not be aware of any JDBC/JPA artifacts.

Comment: I should have written that I can't use any of the Java 8 time classes as I am still using Java 6 ... thus I won't be able to use java.util.date as this do not have microsec. precision , which I actually need... the conclusion would be that instead of java.sql.timestamp using string in the backing-bean... on the entity level I would have the timestamp and between the backing-bean and the entity I have to do my conversion from string to timestamp...

Comment: I presume this is not very nice as I can't use any of the specified JSF converters but at least I can then use the JSF validator as I am using string in the view